# Isometry of open set in upper half plane with hyperbolic metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

While reading Donaldson's book on Riemann surfaces, I came across the following proposition.

**Proposition**

Let $H$ be upper half plane, $p,\tilde{p} \in H$, and
$f: N \rightarrow \tilde{N}$ be a diffeomorphism from an open neighborhood of $p$ to
a neighborhood of $\tilde{p}$. Then, if $f$ is an oriented isometry of the
hyperbolic metric, it is the restriction of a map defined by an element of
$PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ .

I tried to prove it, but could not. Could you please tell me how to show it? Thank you very much.

Comment: The point is that since the map is an isometry of a complete connected Riemannian manifold, then the diffeomorphism extends to a unique isometry of H. This extension is by continuity of the differential also orientation preserving so in particular it Will preserve the associated Kähler form hence also the complex structure. Therefore the extended isometry is a biholomorphism. It follows now by the classification of biholomorphisms of the upper half plane that it must be given by  Möbius transformation i.e. An element of Psl(2,R). Hope this was of use.

Comment: @LBE: Sadly, your suggestion is off: You are correct about uniqueness, but the equation is about existence.  In general, an isometry between open subsets of a Riemannian manifold  does not extend to an isometry of the entire manifold. For hyperbolic plane one has to use some special properties of the hyperbolic plane in order to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: You should tell us what do you already know about isometries of the hyperbolic plane. For instance, do you know what the isometry group is? Do you know that it acts transitively on the orthonormal frame bundle?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  : Thank you for your comments. I know the definition of an isometry group and that the oriented isometry group of an upper half-plane is $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$, which acts as Mobius map.

Comment: I read a book on differential geometry and found the proposition that for two isometries, if the value at a point and the derivative agree, then they agree.
I thought that if I could find an element of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ which maps $p$ to $\tilde{p}$ and its derivative at $p$ coincides with given isometry $f$, then the desired result would follow.

Comment: It was implied (Albeit vaguely) in My response: Existence follows by extension via the exponential map (which it must agree with where it is already defined by the isometry condition and completeness of the upper Half plane) . Then one needs to know that Surfaces of negative curvature has no conjugate points which are the critical values of the exponential map, so the extension is a global diffeomorphism. This is then also an isometry so by my previous argument you are done.

Comment: Then you are on the right track: Given any two pairs $(p,v)$, $(q,w)$ where $p, q$ are points in the hyperbolic plane, $v\in T_pH^2$, $w\in T_qH^2$ are unit tangent vectors, there exists an element  $f\in PSL(2,R)$ such that $f(p)=q$ and $df(v)=w$. This is called **transitivity** of the action of $PSL(2,R)$ on the unit tangent bundle of the hyperbolic plane $H^2$. Usually, one proves this fact while establishing that $PSL(2,R)$ is the full group of orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane. If you check the proof that you say you know, you will probably find this as well.